# How to make my TextView wrapping content and respect a maximum width

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I have a constraintLayout with three views (ImageView, TextView, TextView) 
like this : [image: my constraintLayout layout]

I want the green `TextView` to be `wrap_content` and have also a maximum width, I don't have the exact value of the maximum with but my `TextView` should respect the minimum margin of `16dp`. otherwise it will be multilines.
Can you please help me out with this? 
Regards

Comment: post xml code please

Comment: have you tried using `android:layout_width:"wrap_content"` along with `app:layout_constrainedWidth="true"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap the green `TextView` inside a `RelativeLayout`:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:text="Text1"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/text1"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:background="@color/colorAccent"
            android:text="TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT "/>

    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

It behaves like this:

Short text

[image: short text]

Long text

[image: long text]

Comment: I think this is not the way you are supposed to use constraint layout.

Comment: Try using barriers available in constraint layout.

Comment: The idea of using constraint layout is to avoid having to nested views, we should not do that

Answer (score 13):

From version 1.1.0 of ConstraintLayout.
This issue is resolved by using

**app:layout_constrainedWidth=”true”**

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="TextView TextView TextView TextView TextView TextViewTextView TextView TextView TextView TextView TextView "
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```